# Python while loop keeping running total

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm working on a project that will add up the numbers that are assigned to buttons and once the value has been met or exceeded it will stop and display another message. Right now I'm running into a road block on figuring out how to keep a running tally on the over all total. Below is what I have so far any guidance will be appreciated. One issue I noticed when I select 10 it doesn't stop the loop also.

```
import time
from time import sleep
import Adafruit_CharLCD as LCD

lcd = LCD.Adafruit_CharLCDPlate()

while True:
    x= 1
    y= 10
    z= 5
    a= 0

    lcd.message("Today's Lunch\n only $10 ") #This displays beginning message
    lcd.set_color(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)

    while a<=10:

        if lcd.is_pressed(LCD.RIGHT):
            lcd.clear()
            lcd.set_color(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
            lcd.message('  Total: $')
            lcd.message("%02d" % (a+y))
            sleep(1)

        elif lcd.is_pressed(LCD.LEFT):
            lcd.clear()
            lcd.set_color(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
            lcd.message('  Total: $')
            lcd.message("%02d" % (a+x))
            sleep(1)
        elif lcd.is_pressed(LCD.DOWN):
            lcd.clear()
            lcd.set_color(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
            lcd.message('  Total: $')
            lcd.message("%02d" % (a+z))
            sleep(1)
    else:
        lcd.clear()
        lcd.set_color(1.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        lcd.message('Enjoy \n Your Paper')
        sleep(4)
```

Comment: `a` is never changed inside the loop.

Comment: How would I set up a to change I was drawing a blank on how for it to change per button I know I could start it as a=a+ this where I was getting stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `a` inside the loop, e.g. add `y`, `x` or `z` to `a` on keypress:

```
import time
from time import sleep
import Adafruit_CharLCD as LCD

COINS = {
    LCD.RIGHT: 10,
    LCD.LEFT: 1,
    LCD.DOWN: 5,
}

TOTAL = 10

lcd = LCD.Adafruit_CharLCDPlate()
while True:
    lcd.message("Today's Lunch\n only $10 ") #This displays beginning message
    lcd.set_color(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    amount = 0
    while amount < TOTAL:
        for key, coin in COINS.items():
            if lcd.is_pressed(key):
                amount += coin
                lcd.clear()
                lcd.set_color(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
                lcd.message('  Total: $')
                lcd.message("%02d" % amount)
                sleep(1)
    lcd.clear()
    lcd.set_color(1.0, 1.0, 0.0)
    lcd.message('Enjoy \n Your Paper')
    sleep(4)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is that you're never updating `a`. The statement you're probably expecting to do that:

```
lcd.message("%02d" % (a+y))
```

just calculates the value of `a+y`. It doesn't change the value of `a` or `y`. In fact, you're never assigning any other value to `a` besides the one it starts with.

The solution: after the above line, just add this:

```
a = a + y
```

or, if you want to be even more concise,

```
a += y
```

and do the same for the blocks concerning `x` and `z`.

Comment: Thanks I will try this, my issue I was trying to find an overall way above the button codes not inside them directly. I thought that wouldn't update the overall total.